# Build custom SharePoint home page using SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

I need to customize home page of my SharePoint site online using SPFx (custom list, widgets.....)

Can you please provide me some tutorial to do that?

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint online modern experience, you can develop web parts using SharePoint Framework (SPFx).

Check below Microsoft official documentations for same:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build & deploy your first web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Also, you can check below GitHub repository where for SPFx samples submitted by community members. You can use these web parts as it is or you can download the code and enhance it as per your requirements:

[SPFx Web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts//tree/main/samples/)

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer , so can you please give me more details how i can adapt existing codes in GitHub to work for me?

Comment: Check this: https://sharepointstuff.com/2019/06/17/how-to-deploy-spfx-sample-webparts/